# subtract values from elements in a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have two vectors with the values

```
2.123, 2.111, 9.222
1.22, 4.33, 2.113
```

I want to subtract the first element of each Vector with each other, the second element of each Vector, and the third. so

```
abs(2.123-1.22)
abs(2.111-4.33)
abs(9.222-2.113)
```

I'm pretty sure you have to create a for loop but I'm not sure how to approach this problem as I am new to C++. Thank you all for your help.

The code below is a general concept of what I have

```
std::vector<double> data1, vector<double> data2, vector<double> result;
std::cout << "Enter in data#1 ";
std::cin >> data1;

std::cout << "Enter in data#2 ";
std::cin >> data2;

for (int i=0;i<data1.size();i++){
    //start subtracting the values from each other and have them stored in another Vector
```

Comment: You should first figure out how you're going to get data *into* the vector. `std::cin >> data1;` is not going to work.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you do not know yet standard algorithms as suggested here algorithm `std::transform` you can write an equivalent code using an ordinary for statement. For example

```
std::vector<double> a { 2.123, 2.111, 9.222 };
std::vector<double> b { 1.22, 4.33, 2.133 }; 
std::vector<double> c( a.size(), 0.0 );


for ( std::vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ )
{
   c[i] = std::abs( a[i] - b[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Assuming they are both the same size:

```
std::vector<double> a;
std::vector<double> b;
// fill in a and b
std::vector<double> result;
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::back_inserter(result), [&](double l, double r)
{
    return std::abs(l - r);
});
```

Comment: It would be nice to reserve in result before std::transform

Comment: @HumamHelfawi If performance is a concern, yes.  However, it is not necessary when using `std::back_inserter`.

Answer (score 12):

You'd probably (at least normally) want to do this with `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<double> a{2.123, 2.111, 9.222}, 
                    b{1.22, 4.33, 2.133}, 
                    c;

std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::back_inserter(c),
    [](double a, double b) { return fabs(a-b); });
```

Comment: is it ok to use transform if I want to do the subtraction "in place" (ie. like a `-=`) : `std::transform(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),a.begin(),std::minus<double>());`? I tried it and got expected results, but I am not sure if that will always work.

Comment: @tobi303: Yes, the standard explicitly gives permission for the result iterator to be equal to to either `a.begin()` or `b.begin()`.

Comment: It would be nice to reserve in result before std::transform